# Content Security Policy error when trying to integrate Stripe Payment

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, redux, stripe-payments

**What i'm trying to do**

Right now I have a project built with React & Redux in typescript. That works with a .Net API. I'm trying to integrate Stripe payment system into my project.

**My problem is**

When i follow the documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react I add everything as required and set up my project as such. But when I call `loadStripe()` or when I try to import and add the `<PaymentElement/>`. Im hit with these following errors.

[image]
[image]

- Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).
- Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://m.stripe.com/6. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

I've attachted an Image of the error logs as well as my console log for my `apiResult` and my `userInput` so you have an idea of what data I'm returning.

```
import React from "react";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { PaymentForm } from "../Components/Layout/Page/Payment";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { PaymentElement } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

export default function Payment() {
  const {
    state: { apiResult, userInput },
  } = useLocation();

  console.log(apiResult);
  console.log(userInput);

   const stripePromise = loadStripe(
     "MY-PRIVATE-STRIPE-KEY"
   );
   const options = {
     // passing the client secret obtained from the server
     clientSecret: apiResult.clientSecret,
   };

  return <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
       <PaymentElement />
    </Elements>;
}
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RedMangoAPI.Data;
using RedMangoAPI.Models;
using System.Net;
using Stripe;

namespace RedMangoAPI.Controllers
{
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class PaymentController : ControllerBase
  {

    protected ApiResponse _response;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public PaymentController(IConfiguration configuration, ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
      configuration = configuration;
      _db = db;
      _response = new();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ApiResponse>> MakePayment(string userId)
    {
      ShoppingCart shoppingCart = _db.ShoppingCarts
        .Include(u => u.CartItems)
        .ThenInclude(u => u.MenuItem).FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);

      if (shoppingCart == null || shoppingCart.CartItems == null || shoppingCart.CartItems.Count() == 0)
      {
        _response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        _response.isSuccess = false;
        return BadRequest(_response);
      }

      #region Create Payment Intent 
      StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "MY-SECRET-KEY";
      shoppingCart.CartTotal = shoppingCart.CartItems.Sum(u => u.Quantity * u.MenuItem.Price);

      PaymentIntentCreateOptions options = new()
      {
        Amount = (int)(shoppingCart.CartTotal * 100),
        Currency = "aud",
        PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
        {
          "card",
        }
      };

      PaymentIntentService service = new();
      PaymentIntent response = service.Create(options);
      shoppingCart.StripePaymentItentId = response.Id;
      shoppingCart.ClientSecret = response.ClientSecret;

      #endregion
      _response.Result = shoppingCart;
      _response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
      return Ok(_response);
    }
  }
}
```

My payment works with Stripe through my API though just not on my Client. See example below.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated been stuck for the past 2 hours on this.

Comment: how are you handling the request in the backend?

Comment: Http post. Everything works on my backend though I updated my post so you can see that it works through my API i did. Just isn't working on the client side unless im missing something else. I can add code though if needed

Comment: Yeah. The code would be helpful

Comment: Hey man I've updated it so it shows the backend as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've deployed a CSP in your website. If so, you should configure the directives according to this [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy)

Comment: That did solve that problem specifically now im having an issue with 4 other items. Is there a global sort of way to include these items below without having to independently call each one in my meta tag ? Error example below   

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js (“script-src”).

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js (“script-src”).